# Can I see the values of the Variables References in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I see the values of the Variable References in Visual Studio Code (e.g `${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename} and so on`) - the full path of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the [Variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_how-can-i-know-a-variables-actual-value) doc page.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo ${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking more like within IDE options - without running task

Comment: @JanuszDalecki How often do you need to do this, compared to how much effort it is to write a GUI for this, it is well documented what each value of each variable is and its name is also pretty spot on.